# Loop in mysql query fetching first result only

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

**Table 1 containing course related lecturer's id**

```
id   | course_id   | lecturer_id
1    | Course-1    | ABCD1
2    | Course-1    | WXYZ1
3    | Course-2    | ABCD1
4    | Course-2    | QWER4
```

**Table 2 containing lecturer's details**

```
id   | lecturer_unique_id   | lecturer_name
1    | ABCD1                | Mr XYZ
2    | WXYZ1                | Mrs BBD
3    | QWER4                | Miss KKH
```

I want to fetch Lecturer name with query for table 1.

But it is fetching only first result.

Code :

```
<?php
    $firstquery = "select * from course_related_lecturer_data(table_1) where course_id = 'Course-1'";
    $firstresult = $database->get_results($firstquery );
        foreach($firstresult as  $value){
            $lecturer_unique_id = $value['lecturer_id'];
            $secondquery = "select * from lecturer(table_2) where lecturer_unique_id='$lecturer_unique_id '";

            $secondresult = $database->get_results($secondquery );
             foreach ($secondresult as $lecturerdata){
        ?> 

            <?php echo $lecturerdata['lecturer_name'];?><br>

        <?php } ?>
<?php }  ?>
```

Expected Result is

```
1. Mr XYZ
2. Mrs BBD
```

But I am Getting Only

```
1. Mr XYZ
```

second name is not getting retreived. Why Looping is not working here ?

Comment: Check your results you are querying, add a print_r($firstresult); right after you set the variable. Do you see both results? If not, then your query is not retrieving both records. Do you have access to phpMyAdmin? Can you run the query in the database and retrieve both rows? Try adjusting your query to: "select * from course_related_lecturer_data(table_1) where course_id LIKE 'Course-1'"

Comment: @DustinCochran I tried with this code on separate page, also tried with LIKE option..But only getting first result...

Comment: @DustinCochran with print_r($firstresult), it is showing both lecturer_unique_id but showing first Lecturer Name Only

Comment: You have an unwanted space in your 2nd query `$secondquery = "select * from lecturer(table_2) where lecturer_unique_id='$lecturer_unique_id '";` in `'$lecturer_unique_id '`. Remove that see if that changes anything. If it doesn't `print_r` the value from database and check what data are you getting.